# BitTorrent: How do peers connect to each other even in the absence of port forwarding?

Tags: bittorrent, portforwarding

When you download a file using BitTorrent, you can download parts of the file from others who already have the file or from the original host.  Once you've finished downloading the file, you too can help others download it by sending them parts of it.

How are peers able to connect to each other even if they are behind routers that don't forward any incoming connections to them?  Does the original host help with this somehow?

Comment: Is this question off-topic here?  Should it be moved to a different SE site?

Comment: I think so, no programming here but I can you give a minimal answer that when you download a file you connect to a Tracker who tells you to connect to other computers in a case you are under a NAT there are several ways to talk like skype - you talk with a server that connects between the peers. Cheers.

Comment: I don't see how this question is off topic. It's a valid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your router does not support upnp, many bittorrent implementations will try to connect to other peers using NAT punchthrough (see http://www.raknet.net/raknet/manual/natpunchthrough.html for some examples).

If you cannot punch through, that just means that you cannot host a connection.  You can still make a connection with another host and send/receive packets to them.  It's only when both parties are behind routers that can't be punched through that there is a problem.  In this case, no data can be directly sent between the peers.